# docker-compose.yml with nginx can't share volume

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose, volumes

I'm trying to make the directory being served by nginx also available on host.
I'm running on linux/ubuntu
Part of Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:12.19.1-alpine as builder
... # some commands
RUN yarn build --outputHashing=all --output-path=/app/dist/ 

FROM nginx:1.14.1-alpine
VOLUME /var/cache/nginx
COPY docker/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
RUN rm -rf /var/dist/*
COPY --from=builder /app/dist/ /var/dist
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  app:
    image: name-image
    deploy:
      labels:
        ...       
    tty: true
    networks:
      - proxy
      - my_net
    volumes:
      - /var/apps/myWeb/dist:/var/dist
```

When I deploy without the last two lines above (volumes) the site works and when I run the command below I see that the files are in the /var/dist directory inside the container:
. docker exec -it <container-id> sh
. ls /var/dist
However, when I run with the indicated volume lines, as the directory /var/apps/myWeb/dist is empty on the host, in the container the directory /var/dist is empty as well. How do I make both of them have the build result?

I tried alternatives giving the volume a name, but the container did not start:

```
    volumes:
      - nginx_data:/var/dist
volumes:
  nginx_data:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /var/apps/myWeb/dist
      o: bind
```

Does someone know what I did wrong?

**Solved.**
I finally managed to fix it:
volumes:
- nginx_data:/var/dist
volumes:
nginx_data:
driver_opts:
o: bind
type: nfs
device: /var/apps/myWeb/dist

Thanks

Comment: You put the build files on your host machine in `/var/apps/myWeb/dist` before you bind mount it.

Comment: I'm just linking that question because it explains volume shadowing - I don't necessarily endorse the solution.

Comment: I had tried the suggestions that were in the presented link, but I was not able to identify why I could not run the container. I edited my question with the solution. Thanks

Comment: The error is that driver_opts was not accepting type: none